# Is Sobolev limit of bijective maps surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory, quasiconformal

This is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3803826/is-sobolev-limit-of-bijective-maps-surjective).

Let $\Omega_1,\Omega_2 \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be open, connected, bounded, with non-empty $C^1$ boundaries. Let $f_n:\bar\Omega_1 \to \bar\Omega_2$ be $C^1$ be **bijective** maps with $\det(df_n)>0$, and suppose that $f_n$ converges to a $C^1$ function $f: \bar\Omega_1 \to \bar\Omega_2$ strongly in $W^{1,2}$.

> **Question:** Must $f$ be surjective?

*Note that $f$ is surjective if and only if $|f^{-1}(y)| \le 1$ a.e. on $\Omega_2$:*

By the area formula
$$
 \int_{\Omega_1} \det df_n  = \int_{\Omega_2} |f_n^{-1}(y)|=\text{Vol}(\Omega_2),
$$
so
$$
\int_{\Omega_2} |f^{-1}(y)|= \int_{\Omega_1} \det df  =\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega_1} \det df_n=\text{Vol}(\Omega_2).
$$
This implies the claim.